# How to create a raster time series from vrt file in python

Tags: python, gdal, netcdf

I converted bunch of .tiff files into .vrt with gdal (Raster Virtual Format)

```
gdalbuildvrt -separate testvrt.vrt data/*.tif
```

is there anyway to create a timeseries NetCDF file from .vrt !?

**testvrt.vrt**

```
<VRTDataset rasterXSize="8000" rasterYSize="8000">
  <SRS>PROJCS["Azimuthal_Equidistant",GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Azimuthal_Equidistant"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_center",8.5],PARAMETER["longitude_of_center",21.5],PARAMETER["false_easting",5621452.01998],PARAMETER["false_northing",5990638.42298],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]]]</SRS>
  <GeoTransform>  6.0000000000000000e+06,  7.5000000000000000e+01,  0.0000000000000000e+00,  6.0000000000000000e+06,  0.0000000000000000e+00, -7.5000000000000000e+01</GeoTransform>
  <VRTRasterBand dataType="Int16" band="1">
    <NoDataValue>-9.99900000000000E+03</NoDataValue>
    <ComplexSource>
      <SourceFilename relativeToVRT="1">data_sample/R20060111_075725___SIG0__ASAWS___M1VVD_TUW_SGRT15A00_AF075M_E060N054T6.tif</SourceFilename>
      <SourceBand>1</SourceBand>
      <SourceProperties RasterXSize="8000" RasterYSize="8000" DataType="Int16" BlockXSize="8000" BlockYSize="1" />
      <SrcRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="8000" ySize="8000" />
      <DstRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="8000" ySize="8000" />
      <NODATA>-9999</NODATA>
    </ComplexSource>
  </VRTRasterBand>
  <VRTRasterBand dataType="Int16" band="2">
    <NoDataValue>-9.99900000000000E+03</NoDataValue>
    <ComplexSource>
      <SourceFilename relativeToVRT="1">data_sample/R20060114_080443___SIG0__ASAWS___M1VVD_TUW_SGRT15A00_AF075M_E060N054T6.tif</SourceFilename>
      <SourceBand>1</SourceBand>
      <SourceProperties RasterXSize="8000" RasterYSize="8000" DataType="Int16" BlockXSize="8000" BlockYSize="1" />
      <SrcRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="8000" ySize="8000" />
      <DstRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="8000" ySize="8000" />
      <NODATA>-9999</NODATA>
    </ComplexSource>
  </VRTRasterBand>
...
```

How to create a raster time series from vrt file in python into NetCDF4 format ?

Comment: Have you tried `gdal_translate -of NetCDF testvrt.vrt testncdf.nc`?

Comment: @Kersten the problem with `gdal_translate` is **timeseries**, you don't get the temporal dimension.

Comment: The temporal dimension is represented in the different bands/layers , as invoked with `gdalbuildvrt -separate`. Are you saying you can't convert a multi-layer dataset to NetCDF?

Comment: @Kersten I used the `gdalbuildvrt -separate` as you can see above. yes that is a problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can convert to vrt with separate band as you did. also make text file of your image paths which you could retrieve the time from them.
then load them into your code.

Look at this [POST](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/176990/write-stacks-of-geotiff-image-to-netcdf-by-chunk-size?noredirect=1#comment265765_176990) which I posted, to see how to write them in NetCDF fotmat.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is way I was searching for.